# Java: Formatting an output that contains an integer and array

Tags: java, formatting, printf

Good evening everyone,

I am attempting some practice questions for my computer science final and I'm having a little trouble getting my output to match exactly what it's supposed to. I'm not sure if it's a limitation of my compiler or if I'm just not quite getting it wrong.

Basically, I'm given a two-dimensional array and I have to output that array with a number in front of each index that counts up. I have that, my problem is that the output isn't formatted correctly.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

This is what it looks like:
[image]

I did quite a bit of google and I just can't figure it out. Given what it needs to look like, I can tell that the numbers and Strings are right-aligned, so compensated for that and I also added a tab character after each String to ensure separation between the String and the next integer. However, for some reason, things aren't all right aligned correctly.

Here is my formatted output code:

```
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

          System.out.printf("%2d", count); //Prints each count, right aligned with a width of two.
          System.out.printf("%15s", seasons[i][j]); //Prints each season right aligned with a width of 15 
          // (largest String is 9 characters).
          System.out.printf("\t"); //Adds a tab after the previous season to align the next number.
          count++; //Increases count
     }

     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: For starters, you're not using a fixed-width font.

Comment: Okay, I just googled that and that seems to make sense. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use anything not taught in class, so specifying the font is out of the question. That said, is it possible then that my formatting is correct, just the font itself is causing the issue?

Comment: You took some screenshot. Normally output goes to a terminal either in your IDE or containing a command line, and those are always fixed-width out of the box. Where is this text?

Comment: The first screenshot is from a .pdf, the second one is from my IDE's output tab.

Comment: What IDE, and did you change the setting to use proportional?

Comment: Pico Compiler for iOS and no, only options I have are to change the background color of the IDE and the font size of the IDE. That said, I'm not too concerned if my code doesn't match if it's a compiler issue and not a code issue. If the code is correct then I'm happy, I just am unsure if the issue is with the code or the compiler's output.

Comment: Perhaps copy and paste into Notepad or something equivalent? It's _probably_ okay, but I very strongly recommend using a Real IDE going forward.